# Create code inspection for views in Android Studio for Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, code-inspection

I would like to create a kotlin code inspection for invoking of view's id reference.
In settings I cannot see an option for adding a kotlin code inspection.

[image]

My goal is to inspect when I don't write a nullable id reference to .xml's type of widget in a kotlin class.

For example:

**etMain.text** = "" -> and it should inspect that I could write with nullable type: **etMain?.text** = ""

Do you have any idea how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10176. Please follow it for updates.